# What is the trick to run a member function in the back-end without slowing down the main application?

Tags: c++, qt

Sorry I don't know how to phrase this in the title, maybe someone could help me.

I am starting to make a Qt application, let's say, the application will first show `N` points on the screen. Then we have a function now, called `movePoints`, when it is called, these points will be moved according to some algorithms.

Now when `N` is small, everything looks very smooth, it works very well without any problem. But if `N` is very large, the whole GUI sucks because `movePoints` is running. So whenever I touch the application window now, it becomes unresponding. But I know lots of programs seem to be able to let the `movePoints` function run in the back-end (with a progress bar in the status bar or something) without slowing down the main application. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep your application responsive to user interactions, you should use the processEvents function. (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents)

If you'd rather have the operation occur in the background you can use the QtConcurrent module and use the asynchronous run function (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use a QTimer for an interrupt or a QThread to bring the calculation out of the main loop. See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate thread to perform calculations in the background without blocking the Qt event loop. See [QThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html) and [QConcurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrent.html). It's common practice in processing-intensive Qt applications to have the main thread handle the GUI while "back-end" calculations are done in "worker" threads.

If rendering the data (rather than just calculating the next state) is also an intensive operation, you can also use your worker thread(s) to create a QImage, QGraphicsScene, or similar type of object, and send it pre-built to the UI thread.

If you're limited to a single thread (e.g. your platform doesn't really support threads), then you can take your algorithm and intersperse calls to [QCoreApplication::proccessEvents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents), which will make the GUI more responsive while the activity runs. I find that using actual threads tends to be the simpler and more maintainable approach, though.